# Istio metrics - istio_request_duration_milliseconds_count and istio_request_duration_milliseconds_sum

Tags: prometheus, istio, envoyproxy, istio-sidecar, istio-prometheus

I see these two metrics emitted by istio sidecars, but i am unable to find documentation on what they are.

istio_request_duration_milliseconds_count
istio_request_duration_milliseconds_sum

What do these two metrics signify?

Answer (score 2):

These are auxilliary metrics exposed by [Prometheus-compatible histogram](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#histogram) named `istio_request_duration_milliseconds`.

This histogram tracks the distribution of istio request durations.

The `istio_request_duration_milliseconds_count` metric counts the total number of istio requests since its last start.

The `istio_request_duration_milliseconds_sum` metric tracks the sum of all the request duratioms since the last start of tye istio.

These metrics can be used for calculating the average request duration over arbitrary lookbehind window specified in square brackets of the following query:

```
increase(istio_request_duration_milliseconds_sum[5m])
  /
increase(istio_request_duration_milliseconds_count[5m])
```

See more info about this histogram (aka `distribution`) in [istio docs](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/metrics/).